# Passing back data from Electron function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

I'm opening the Electron open dialog:

```
var electron = require('electron');
const {dialog} = electron.remote;

var browsedFile = dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile' ], filters: [{name: 'Scripts', extensions: ['sh']}]} );
```

I have the Electron function declared like

```
function readFileAsString(filePath, functionCallback) {

  var fs = require('fs');
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    functionCallback(err, data);
  });

}

exports.readFileAsString = readFileAsString;
```

Then I'm calling the Electron function, passing in a callback function

```
var openScriptFile = electron.remote.require('./main.desktop').readFileAsString;
openScriptFile(filePath, this.afterOpenScriptFileCallback);
```

Inside the callback function, I'm trying to access variables in the component via `this.myVar`, but they're undefined, presumably out of scope?

```
afterOpenScriptFileCallback(err, data) {
    if(err){
      console.log('error opening file: ', err);
    } else {
      this.myVar = data;
    }
}
```

How do I access `this.myVar` variables from inside the callback from Electron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get rid of the `electron.remote.require`, there are very few cases where that actually makes sense, just use regular `require`.

Then you probably need to make this change:

```
openScriptFile(filePath, this.afterOpenScriptFileCallback.bind(this))
```

I suggest you read through [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work/3127440#3127440) to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Thanks!  I did read about `bind` but was using it in the wrong spot.